# Three.js JSONLoader; Textures not loading

Tags: javascript, 3d, textures, three.js

Using the blender exporter packaged with Three.js I exported the `.blend` file from [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20140525161350/http://www.blenderguru.com:80/videos/create-an-underground-subway-scene-part-2-of-2/). I'm a huge noob when it comes to blender so what I did was simple:

1. Open the file, and export it with the exporter
2. Open the UV/Image Editor
3. Save a copy of each texture next to the exported JSON (using the correct names)
4. Modify the images to have dimensions that are a power of 2

So I just wanted to see if I could load this object as the level to walk around on in an experiment I am working on. The mesh loads fine, but there are no textures. I modified the Three.js source to do a `console.log` when it creates the texture images (in `Loader` source) to make sure the URL is right and that the images do actually load, which they do.

Here is the code:

```
var jLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
jLoader.createModel(map.data, function(geometry) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(),
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    mesh.scale.set(50, 50, 50);

    scene.add(mesh);
}, map.texturePath);
```

I use `createModel` since I load the JSON data myself using my own loader. `map.data` contains the exported JSON, `map.texturePath` contains the path (no trailing slash) to the directory with the textures; specifically `'js/game/maps/subway'`. The JSON is 30MB so I will not post it here, but I can tell you that the materials are listed, as well as the `uvs`. Here is the metadata:

```
"metadata" :
{
    "formatVersion" : 3.1,
    "generatedBy"   : "Blender 2.63 Exporter",
    "vertices"      : 474135,
    "faces"         : 236963,
    "normals"       : 168623,
    "colors"        : 0,
    "uvs"           : [3117],
    "materials"     : 1,
    "morphTargets"  : 0,
    "bones"         : 0
},

"scale" : 1.000000,
```

I do notice that it says `"materials": 1` when the `materials` array is actually length 74. I don't know enough about the format to know if this is an issue or not.

Now when rendered you can see places there should be textures are just blank.

[image: Subway - No Textures]
<sub>(source: [pantherdev.com](http://static.pantherdev.com/misc/subway.png))</sub>

I tried waiting to ensure they didn't just take a long time to load, tried changing the material I instantiate, tried not scaling the mesh, tried putting logs in three.js to ensure the images are loading (they are).

Looking closer I can see that at least 1 texture does show up:

[image: Subway - Texture Loaded]
<sub>(source: [pantherdev.com](http://static.pantherdev.com/misc/subway2.png))</sub>

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, or what to try next.

If it would help to see a live demo, you can [try it here](http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client) though it may take a minute or two to load the subway JSON as my server is just a box in my living room; not exactly a network speed demon.

Any help is appreciated, sorry for such a long post; just wanted to give all the information I had.

---

**Edit**

I tried to use absolute paths to the textures, and even went so far as to modify the `mapDifuse` properties of the materials in the JSON to try and fix the issue, to no avail.

---

**Edit 2**

After doing some more debugging with WebGL-Inspector I found the following errors in my Web Console:

```
[18:36:35.395] Error: WebGL: DrawElements: bound vertex attribute buffers do not have sufficient size for given indices from the bound element array @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:1933
[18:36:35.751] Error: WebGL: No further warnings will be reported for this WebGL context (already reported 32 warnings) @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:1933
```

When I capture a frame, I get even more information:

```
[18:38:12.349] Frame 791 errors: @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9780
[18:38:12.349] ---------------------- @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9781
[18:38:12.349]  INVALID_OPERATION <= drawElements(TRIANGLES, 306, UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0) @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9787
[18:38:12.349]    - @http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:4155 @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9792
[18:38:12.349]    - @http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/js/game/vendor/three/three.min.js:403 @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9792
[18:38:12.350]    - n@http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/js/game/vendor/three/three.min.js:346 @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9792
[18:38:12.350]    - @http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/js/game/vendor/three/three.min.js:408 @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9792
[18:38:12.350]    - animate@http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/isolate.html:108 @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9792
[18:38:12.350]    - @http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:2307 @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9792
  ... A WHOLE LOT OF THIS ...
[18:38:12.358]  INVALID_OPERATION <= drawElements(TRIANGLES, 6, UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0) @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9787
[18:38:12.358]    - @http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:4155 @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9792
[18:38:12.358]    - @http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/js/game/vendor/three/three.min.js:403 @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9792
[18:38:12.358]    - n@http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/js/game/vendor/three/three.min.js:346 @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9792
[18:38:12.358]    - @http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/js/game/vendor/three/three.min.js:408 @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9792
[18:38:12.358]    - animate@http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/isolate.html:108 @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9792
[18:38:12.358]    - @http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:2307 @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9792
[18:38:12.359]   @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:9796

[18:38:12.126] Error: WebGL: bindBuffer: target: invalid enum value 0x0 @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:4163
[18:38:12.133] Error: WebGL: generateMipmap: Level zero of texture is not defined. @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:3668
[18:38:12.927] Error: WebGL: bindBuffer: target: invalid enum value 0x0 @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:4163
[18:38:14.156] Error: WebGL: DrawElements: bound vertex attribute buffers do not have sufficient size for given indices from the bound element array @ http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/lib/gli.all.js:2745
```

I think it is right to assume that my JSON has some incorrect or missing values, however I am not sure how to remedy the situation. Like I mentioned in a comment (and at the start of this post), I exported the `.blend` file using the exporter packaged with Three.js; what else would I need to do?

---

**Edit 3**

Using the WebGL-Inspector I have pulled a little more info about the actual calls that are failing. Here is the debug info for the [working "649" texture](http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/working.html) and the [broken "rust" texture](http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/broken.html) though the texture doesn't show on the linked pages the data is all there if it helps someone (the textures do show on the WebGL-Inspector on the isolate page, just not on the exported pages I linked).

Comment: Could you create an isolated test? It's hard to dive into what you have currently setup.

Comment: @mrdoob I copied the example from here: http://www.aerotwist.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/ and added my code to the very bottom of the page (also removed the sphere and made the demo bigger). The isolated test can be seen here: http://static.pantherdev.com/dev/arena/client/isolate.html make sure to give the JSON a good minute or two to load (slow server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up abandoning try to get this to work, I think the model itself was improperly created. The UVs didn't seem to map to the model correctly, and was broken on export. I never managed to get it working, but was able to load other textured models that were obviously different even when just loaded into Blender.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your uvs aren't complete for some of your materials because webgl inspector throws errors when some materials are used. I still need to examine of what exactly happened but that seem what your problem is. The problem is probably the JSON file.

Comment: Strange, I exported the file directly from blender using the exporter plugin provided with three.js (v3.1). Is there more that I need to do besides simply open the `.blend` file and export it?

Comment: actually can you try with the latest version of exporter becuase there seems to be an improvement in the latest exporter:https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender/2.63/scripts/addons/io_mesh_threejs

Answer (score 0):

You must show not metadata but materials array, blender exporter doesn't save texture by default if it missed in materials then try 2-2 from [this tutorial](http://graphic-sim.com/B_basic_export.html).